# Bootstrap - Button group with Label

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to have a button group, but one of the elements being a label.

Similar how Input Groups work with Input Groups Addon.

I basically want the button to look like a button but not have any effect when hovered over.

Best effort at the moment is using `<a>`  with `disabled`, but that makes the colour slightly different to the rest of the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/sctqg038/

[image]

Comment: I think that `<a>` with the `disabled` attribute looks pretty good. What is the color that is different from the rest of the page? If you mean the green, that is because you have `btn-success`. You could change it to `btn-default`. If you are talking about something else, I'm sure you can override it with CSS. Here is a fiddle with `btn-default` used: https://jsfiddle.net/sctqg038/1/

Comment: But I think what you have is the best option. It appears that there is no built-in way to do what you want.

Comment: Right now thinking of just adding 'btn-succes-disabled' class and override the disabled colour to fit the rest of the page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have updated the Fiddle. Just add a id to the button you want to use as a label and give the following css `pointer-events:none`. It won't change the button color.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sctqg038/2/)

**snippet**

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
#label-btn {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="label-btn"  aria-disabled="true">T</a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" aria-label="Import" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Import">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```